# Allowing cross origin requests for http and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, cors

My website supports both http and https protocols. However using the code below in .htaccess file, I can only set one domain to allow CORS requests:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com`

I want to allow CORS for both http and https versions of my site (not just "*") and tried the solutions here:
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

But the problem is that all solutions rely on `Origin` header in the request which may not exist and also is not secure. (anyone can put a origin header in their request)

I want to know if the request has been served over https and use this info to set the proper CORS header. Something like this:

```
SetEnvIf servedOverHttps httpsOrigin=true
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.me env=httpsOrigin

SetEnvIf notServedOverHttps httpOrigin=true
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.me env=httpOrigin
```

How can I find out that it's a https request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `HTTPS` variable?

It will be set to `"on"` for all https requests.
Your .htaccess should look like this

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com             #default
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com env=HTTPS   #override if https
```

Comment: what if one is setting headers programmatically from php file  ?